# I want to find if tv is sony in the output list, how to write xpath

Tags: xpath

How to write Xpath for below code?
I want to verify if TV is sony in the output list

Below is the path shown.

```
<span class="label_con ng-binding"><any translate="" class="ng-scope" style="">TV</any> :   Sony </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
//span[contains(., 'Sony')]
```

see this link: http://xpather.com/srA1KB2q